# How to change database entries due to theme change

Tags: themes, database, migration

I am not Wordpress developer but I have a problem and I do not how to deal with it.

My problem is that I am changing theme due to current theme is outdated.Those themes totally different each other and they use different frontend builder plugins.
My db has about 4k post and related post meta fields. Is there a path to where to start changing db values for new themes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the two themes. Generally speaking, the intent in WordPress is that if you switch your theme, you don't lose functionality. However, some themes do have built-in functionality such as custom post types and custom fields that others won't match.

The best path forward is to make a copy of your site, either locally or as a staging site on your server. Then you can switch themes, see what happens, and determine what if anything you may need to update within content or plugins to make sure you're not losing anything important to your site.

Comment: I installed locally and switched the themes.  I saw post contents have like <oldtheme_title etc. tags. so posts are not shown properly on new theme. do I have to change posts and posts_meta db values? If so, what will new values for old tags ?

Comment: That's not really something anyone else can answer for you. You will have to look and see where the old theme saved the data (into postmeta, or post itself) and then determine whether you need to create a child theme to show that info. Or alternatively, if your site is small enough you could just compare the two sites and start updating the staging site post by post in the Editor, so that all the info is just stored in post content and can be seen in any theme. Once that's done you can basically swap the two sites, making the one with the new theme live.